# Передача пользовательского экземпляра класса через сигналы-слоты

Tags: qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Необходимо из потока вывести в основной поток через сигналы-слоты параметры для дальнейшей обработки. Пересмотрел много разной информации и голова уже порядком устала. Прошу помощи. 
Выдаёт ошибку, пометил в коде:

```
/action_user.cpp:25: error: use of deleted function 'Cargo::Cargo(const Cargo&)'
 case 1:  emit RegistrationSignal(route_signal, action_cargo); break;
                                                            ^

#ifndef ACTION_USER_H
#define ACTION_USER_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include "cargo.h"


class Action_user : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Action_user(QObject *parent = 0);
  void CommandSplit(QByteArray);  // отправляет команды в private и action_cargo
  void Action_route();            //

signals:
  void RegistrationSignal(int, Cargo);

private slots:
  void RegistrationSlot();

private:
  int route_signal;
  Cargo action_cargo;             // рабочий экземпляр класса передачи данных для потока
};
#endif // ACTION_USER_H

#ifndef DB_CONNECT_H
#define DB_CONNECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <action_user.h>

class DB_connect : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit DB_connect(QObject *parent = 0);
  bool createConnection();

signals:
  void createConnectionTrue();
public slots:
  void AddDB(int, Cargo);
};

void registration (Cargo);

#endif // DB_CONNECT_H

//action_user.cpp
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>
#include "action_user.h"
#include "db_connect.h"

Action_user::Action_user(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Action_user::CommandSplit(QByteArray)
{
  route_signal = 0;
  // action_cargo.name_cargo;             // рабочий экземпляр класса передачи данных для потока
}

void Action_user::Action_route()
{
  DB_connect connectDB;
  connect(this, SIGNAL(RegistrationSignal(route_signal, action_cargo)), &connectDB, SLOT(AddDB(route_signal, action_cargo)));
  switch (route_signal) {

// ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ

    case 1:  emit RegistrationSignal(route_signal, action_cargo); break; // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
    default:
      break;
    }
}
void Action_user::RegistrationSlot()
{
}


//db_connect.cpp
#include <QStringList>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QDebug>
#include "db_connect.h"
#include "cargo.h"
#include "action_user.h"

DB_connect::DB_connect(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

bool DB_connect::createConnection()
{
***
}

void DB_connect::AddDB(int route, Cargo action_cargo)
{
  switch (route) {
    case 1: registration(action_cargo); break;
    default:
      break;
    }
}
void registration (Cargo action_cargo)
{
***
}
```

Comment: Как минимум, у вас `action_cargo` - это указатель, а сигнал передает экземпляр класса. Плюс для пользовательских типов необходимо использовать макрос Q_DECLARE_METATYPE

Comment: Поправил, но ситуация не изменилась. Вопрос обновил.

Comment: Вы описание ошибки прочитайте: передавая объект по значению необходим конструктор копирования, он у вас удален. Необходимо его определить, либо использовать указатели

Comment: Класс наследуется от QObject и потому там нет возможности установить конструктор копирования. Как быть в данной ситуации.

Comment: Передалал класс в пользовательский и добавил конструктор копирования. Компилятор перестал выводить ошибки.

Comment: @Pavel Parshin оформите пожалуйста ответ. Я его зачту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: no matching function for call to
>   'Action_user::RegistrationSignal(int&, Cargo*&)'
>        case 1:  emit RegistrationSignal(route_signal, action_cargo); break;

`action_cargo` - это указатель, а сигнал передает экземпляр класса. Плюс для пользовательских типов необходимо использовать макрос [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

> error: use of deleted function 'Cargo::Cargo(const Cargo&)'    case 1: 
>   emit RegistrationSignal(route_signal, action_cargo); break;

Передавая объект по значению необходим конструктор копирования, он у вас удален. Необходимо его определить, либо использовать указатели.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Cargo{
public :
    int x,y,z;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Cargo)
```

Разместить до создания подключения signal-slot:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Cargo>( "Cargo" );
```

Источник: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818557/how-to-register-a-class-for-use-it-in-a-qwebchannel-signal-in-qt).